# Can't install MS SQL Server on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server

I am trying to install Microsoft SQL Server on Ubuntu 21.10 and I am getting an error. I noticed that Microsoft [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't mention 21; so maybe it's not possible yet. But Canonical announcement specifically mentions SQL Server support.

Anyway, when I run `sudo apt install mssql-server` I am getting the following:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> mssql-server : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 but it is not installable

if I try to install `libldap` manually, it just says that unable to locate package. However, when I run `sudo apt install libldap-2.4-2`, I get something more interesting:

```
Package libldap-2.4-2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libldap-common
```

But how do I tell sql server installer to use it?

Maybe I am using a wrong repository? This [guide](https://manjaro.site/how-to-install-microsoft-sql-server-2019-on-ubuntu-21-04/) still uses 20.04 - and there isn't much relevant under 21.

Comment: The guide "still" uses 20.04 because that the current LTS release. Do you really want to only get 18 months of updates for your server? Reasonable business practice is to use LTS, not the most recent version.

Comment: If you take a look at [Microsofts documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15#prerequisites) you'll notice that only LTS releases are supported.

Comment: I looked at Microsoft documentation. I even put a link in the very first paragraph. If 21 is not supported - so be it; despite the fact that it came out 7 months ago, and despite Canonical's statement to the contrary. You don't have to be obnoxious - there are reasons to use beta version of software products, let alone most recent released versions. Doesn't contradict reasonable business practice to use LTS *in production*

Comment: Canonical statement is that 20.04 is LTS, and next LTS would be 22.04, which is still not ready. So 20.04 is the *latest* LTS. We don't consider using products for personal use or for development or for testing here; our goal is production, and it is clear that LTS products should be used and we geneally don't talk here about everything else.

Comment: "We don't consider using products for ... development or for testing here". Is there anything in ServerFault that indicates this? Or it is your personal opinion (as in Мы, Николай Второй). Anyway, now I understand why people come to StackOverflow with questions that more properly belong on ServerFault - they just get better answers there. But I think I got my answer, anyway. Thanks all

Comment: `Is there anything in ServerFault that indicates this?` - There is, this is one of the deeper explanations that is linked from the help section: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to anwser clearly and don't polemic with useless subjects in comments : it's the Microsoft role's to update their product in order to follow system evolution. By the time, we also seen that the OS create sort of aliases for compatibility too ; in instance and in state of the art : mssql seams not to be compatible with Ubuntu 21.10

The guide you used tell Ubuntu to use Ubuntu 20.04 repository, in order to have the right package, that's why it doesn't work natively in 21.10.

So, if you really want to continue to use Ubuntu 21.10 (as temporaly OS it is), you only can add the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories, which is a very not recommanded solution

Answer (score 2):

You can install libldap2.4 on any Debian  based distros from the following link
https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/libldap-2.4-2/download

Comment: do you have install command for debian?

Answer (score 0):

I've circumvented this issue by [installing one of Microsoft provided Docker containers with SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Docker container that you linked is Ubuntu 20... not 21.